# Footnote with no footnotemark

Tags: footnotes

In this MWE I'd like to have the footnote with no footnotemark in text or footnote. I'm surprised that I couldn't find an answer elsewhere on this site - perhaps I haven't looked properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[textheight=4in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\chapternote}[1]{%
\footnote{\emph{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\begin{quotation}
Some introductory material here \ldots
\end{quotation}

\chapternote{Information about this chapter -- without footnotemark,
  please.}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** followup question. I'd like to have normal footnote numbering for all the ordinary `\footnote` s. Footnote counter should reset at the start of each section.

Comment: agreed that the cited question answers this one, but that title really doesn't look promising.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's why I couldn't find it when I asked my question. Keeping this one to point to that one might help people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the traditional footnote mechanism, but you have to make sure that you deal with counters properly. To that end, pass a *value* as the optional argument to `\footnote`, but also set `\thempfn` to not print anything:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[textheight=4in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\chapternote}[1]{{%
  \let\thempfn\relax% Remove footnote number printing mechanism
  \footnotetext[0]{\emph{#1}}% Print footnote text
}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\begin{quotation}
Some introductory material here \ldots
\end{quotation}

\chapternote{Information about this chapter -- without footnotemark,
  please.}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Another option would be to use the symbol "numbering" for footnotes and pass the value 0, since there is no symbol for 0.

```
\newcommand{\chapternote}[1]{{%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
  \footnotetext[0]{\emph{#1}}% Print footnote text
}}
```

Another option is to use a package: [`nccfoots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nccfoots). It provides `\Footenotetext{<marker>}{<footnote>}`

```
\usepackage{nccfoots}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nccfoots
\newcommand{\chapternote}[1]{%
  \Footnotetext{}{\emph{#1}}% Print footnote text
}
```

Comment: Your answer uses the same idea than mine, you were also faster, hence I will delete my answer and upvote yours.

Comment: I've added a followup question - how do I restore ordinary numbering for ordinary footnotes?

Comment: @EthanBolker: I didn't change the ordinary `\footnote` command, so you can/should use that. Restart footnote numbering with each *chapter* you could use `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithin{footnote}{chapter}`. See [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://goo.gl/ZIl7S4).

Comment: @Werner I needed \let\oldthempfn\thempfn%  ... \let\thempfn\oldthempfn% in your first solution to restore footnote behavior.